# jQuery - resize image on mousemove

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, zooming, mousemove

I'm working on an application that allows you to zoom in & out of an image and also pan it if it's zoomed in. You can view it in action on http://picselbocs.com/projects/helsinki-map-application .

During the application's development, I ran into a problem that I can't figure out and fix:

For zooming in/out, you press the left mouse button on the map and then drag the cursor up or down. Pretty much a "click & drag" behavior. The idea is to store the pointer's initial coordinates (when pressing the mouse button) and then on each *mousemove*, give the image a new size (in pixels) based on the distance covered with the cursor.
The problem I've encountered is that right after I press the mouse button and start dragging the cursor, the map moves jerky. It freezes up for a bit, then resizes, then freezes again...It does this for a few seconds, then behaves normally. Although at some point it can do all this again.

If anyone has any ideas as to why this happens and about fixing the problem, I'd appreciate it greatly if you shared them with me.

Best wishes,
Andrei

Comment: By the way, the image is input by an <img> tag. Also, this behavior is visible in both Chrome and Firefox (at least).

Comment: Can you share your code here - ie the jQuery / JavaScript code that is causing the problem

Comment: It's probably best to see it all:  http://picselbocs.com/projects/helsinki-map-application/script.js .

Answer (score 0):

Try stopping animations on your image before resizing it. 
You may also use jquery ui to make your image resizable.

Comment: The image is not resized by animating its dimensions. Only by directly changing the height and width. And jQuery UI is not a solution for me in this case due to several limitations.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know what is your code but you can test it, maybe solve your problem

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
 <div align="center">
  <fieldset style="width:450px;height:320px;">
   <table border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
    <tr><td colspan="2" class="header">MOUSEOVER TO ZOOM
     IMAGE</td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2"></td></tr>
    <tr>
     <td colspan="2">
      <div class="imgcontainer">
       <asp:Image ID="Image1" CssClass="image"
        ImageUrl="~/images/Image8.jpg" runat="server" />
      </div>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </fieldset>
 </div>
</form>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var zoom = 1.1;
var move = -20;
$("#Image1").hover(
function() {
var imgwidth = $("#Image1").width() * zoom;
var imgheight = $("#Image1").height() * zoom;
$(this).animate({ 'width': imgwidth, 'height':
imgheight, 'top': move, 'left': move }, { duration: 200 });
},
function() {
//Reset the image
$(this).animate({ 'width': $(".imgcontainer").width(),
'height': $(".imgcontainer").height(), 'top': '0', 'left': '0' }, {
duration: 100 });
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: and there is some css to set width and height